# If $\int_{t_1}^{t_2} f_n (t) dt$ tends to nonnegative values, then can we generalize to open sets from intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, lebesgue-integral

Let $f_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of integrable functions such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{t_1}^{t_2} f_n(t) dt \to a_{t_1, t_2} \text{ as } n \to \infty
\end{equation}
for a.e. $t_1 \in [0,1]$ and all $t_2 \in [0,1]$ such that $t_2 \geq t_1$. Here, $a_{t_1, t_2} \in [0,\infty)$ for all such $t_1, t_2$'s.

Then, I wonder if the limit still exists for any "open subset" $U \subset (0,1)$.

This seems quite confusing since there is no nonnegativity assumed about $f_n(t)$'s even though $U$ may be expressed as a countable union of disjoint open intervals..

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: So "almost every" $t_1$? But if the sequence of integrals on $[t_1,t_2]$ doesn't converge for some interval, then the limit on the open $U=(t_1,t_2)$ also doesn't converge.

Comment: Actually, it's possible that for every $0 \leq t_1 < t_2 \leq 1$, the sequence converges to $a_{t_1,t_2} = 0$, but the sequence $\int_U f_n(t)\, dt$ is any real sequence you like - converging, negative, bounded non-convergent, or unbounded.